# How to compare data in db2 in two tabls

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
 update  StoreStock 
 set QTY = QTY + $QTY 
 where whStock.QTY >= $QTY
 and StoreStock.PNR = '$prod'"
```

how would i get this to run, getting errors
what  i have is, whStock table's foreign key is Products table and StockStock foreign key is whStock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to check a condition in `Products` table during the update of `StockStock` table.

Suppose `StockStock` table has a foreign key `whStock` which references `ID` column in `Products` table

```
update  StoreStock s
   set QTY = QTY + $QTY 
 where exists (select 1 from Products p where p.ID = s.whStock and p.QTY >= $QTY)
   and s.PNR = '$prod'
```